# IE7 Jquery UI Sortable problem

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Jquery UI sortable in my current project to make boxes drag and drop-able into new columns. It works in all modern browsers apart from ie7, in which you can drag and drop, but when you drop, it completely ruins the content of the box you're dropping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the jQuery UI sortable demos seem to work for me in IE7 and the documentation says they should to too.
Sounds more likely an issue with the CSS of the elements you're dropping into.

I'd start by rebuilding your functionality with no styles or JS other then the jQ UI required and check it works - then start adding back in your HTML and CSS it.

Can you send some code samples and explain how it gets ruined?

Comment: Forgot I'd asked here. I went back and rebuilt it from the demo itself, and somewhere along the line, fixed whatever was going on =)